# Redirect TF_CPP logs to file python

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, sys

I'm running python script in which I intend to save tensorflow logs (regardless of their severity) generated during the execution of the script, to a file so that they don't pop up on the console.

Here's the code snippet:

```
# Setting up Info Logger
import logging, os, sys
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


def setup_logger(fileName=None, level=logging.NOTSET):
    if fileName is None:
        fileName = u'./test.log'

    FORMAT = '%(asctime)s -- %(name)s -- %(levelname)s -- %(message)s'
    logger_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(fileName, 'w')
    logger_file_handler.setLevel(level)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
    logger_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    tf_logger = logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
    tf_logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    tf_logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    tf_logger.propagate = False

    logging.captureWarnings(True)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__.split('.')[0])
    warnings_logger = logging.getLogger('py.warnings')

    logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    warnings_logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)

# Redirect all logs to disk
setup_logger(level=logging.DEBUG)

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

> **Problem**

1) The script saves all logs except the ones of `tensorflow`.

2) If I comment out `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`, then I get the following line on the console:

`2019-12-10 11:51:07.501527: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll`

> **What I've tried**

I found out that the `TF_CPP` environment variable sends these logs to `sys.stderr` (correct me if I'm wrong) which gets printed on the console.

But it may lead to instability as it'll redirect even the tracebacks to log file, if I try to log `stderr`.

> **What I expect**

I intend to get the tensorflow log (like the above one) to appear in the log file.

---

Kindly give your valuable opinion/solution regarding this problem.

Thanks!

Preetkaran

**Python Ver:**   *3.7.5*
**Tensorflow Ver:**    *2.0.0*